# How to write hex value to a register address in c

Tags: c, hex, bitwise-operators

In C, how would you write a hex value to a particular register.

For example if I wanted to write the value 0x12 to the register address of a 0x26 of a particular chip.

The chip in question is the sx1276 which is a transceiver.

thank you

Comment: Probably your vendor can give you an SDK... BTW it is unclear: what HW? 32 bit, 8 bit registers .....etc....

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ptr = 0x26;
*ptr = 0x12;
```

This code will write one byte into the location 0x26.

The type of `ptr` has to be modified to write different sized data types.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS The memory location must exist and be writable for it to run properly. But the above code will compile. This code will also work for a register, if they share the same address space.